# Memory leak problem, could someone explain what this mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am getting a memory leak on the following code line:
[image]

The code-line:

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [qContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

I have been trying to read-up on this and have tried to find the cause of this for quite some time, without success.

Could someone give me a hint where to look? ...and do i understand the "100%" correctly that it indicate that this code line is 100% causing the leak?

**UPDATE**

Some more code:

```
//=========PREPARE CORE DATA DB===========//
if (managedObjectContext == nil) { managedObjectContext = [(FamQuiz_R0_1AppDelegate *)
                                                           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; }

// Define qContext
NSManagedObjectContext *qContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"questions" inManagedObjectContext:qContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [qContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
if ([[info valueForKey:@"qDiff"] intValue] == 1) { 
        [allEasyArrayQ addObject:[info valueForKey:@"idQ"]];
    } else if ([[info valueForKey:@"qDiff"] intValue] == 2) { 
        [allMediumArrayQ addObject:[info valueForKey:@"idQ"]];
    } else if ([[info valueForKey:@"qDiff"] intValue] == 3) { 
        [allHardArrayQ addObject:[info valueForKey:@"idQ"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the fetchrequest and predicate?

Comment: Also give details about the leak if you can.

Comment: Is the fetchRequest object being released (is it either autoreleased *-or-* released manually after executing the fetchRequest?

Comment: fetchRequest is released

Answer (score 0):

You are probably over-retaining the array or the objects inside it later in this method or even outside of this method. The line will only indicate where the objects are created, not where the actual extra retain is performed. For that you'd need to check using Instruments which call stacks retain and release the leaked objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, the 100% means that this leak accounts for 100% of your leaked memory (ie, this is you only leak).

Note if you want to fix the leak you are looking in the wrong place. Leaks tells you which instance is leaking, it's Class and it's memory management history. Try a tutorial like this one http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/

Note, what Leaks can't tell you is the line **where** you are leaking, as the cause of your leak is something you haven't done, as opposed to something you have done (ie you didn't release your object).